# Is there a way to pass a route parameter value that has spaces in it using the Swagger UI?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am using ASP.NET Core and I have an API controller that has a POST action.  The route is /categories/{categoryname}.  The route parameter of categoryname is a string.

I am using Swagger UI.  I want to be able to enter a string with spaces in it- for example: Executive Recruiter

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does Executive%20Recruiter work? (URLs cannot contain non-encoded spaces. Does Swagger encode or not? And if so, before/after it allows said input?)

Comment: @user2864740 No - the variable passed into the controller is: Executive%20Recruiter.

Comment: Server-side controllers are supposed to decode [percent-encoded characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) in URIs according to [RFC 3986 section 2.4](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.4).

Comment: What if you enter "Executive Recruiter" in Swagger UI? Does the parameter value evaluated inside the controller contain the space or %20?

Answer (score 0):

you can encode and decode your data for query string or route values

```
  var s = "Executive Recruiter";
  var encoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(s);  // = Executive%20Recruiter
  var decoded = Uri.UnescapeDataString(encoded); // = Executive Recruiter
```

but it is usually not needed to decode a string, controller decodes it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was I removed the route on the Post Action. In the Swagger UI I dont need to add the %20. Here is what the controller looks like:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ConnectionCategoryModel), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ConnectionCategoryModel>> AddConnectionCategoryAsync(int connectionManagerID, string categoryName)
```